# Mocked object to look like mongoose object

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I am just getting started w/ mocha, sinon and mongoose.

I have a Schemas/Models in mongoose:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  employer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employer' }
});
mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

var EmployerSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});
mongoose.model('Employer', EmployerSchema);
```

An I have a method to help query:

```
var getPersonById = function(id, callback) {
  Person.findById(id, function(err, person) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    // this really could call any mongoose function
    // question is if I mocked the person object is there a good
    // way to mock the populate method that mongoose provides
    person.populate('employer', function(err, populatedPerson) {
      return callback(err, populatedPerson);
    });
  });
}
```

And I am successfully mocking a query to the database:
    var mockedPerson = {
      _id: '1',
      name: 'test'
    };

```
sinon.mock(PersonModel)
  .expects('findById')
  .withArgs("1")
  .yields(null, mockedPerson});
```

Then a call to my function in my test:

```
getPersonById("1", function(err, person) {
   // person is: {name: 'test'};
});
```

However my test fails due to the fact that when I mocked the person object that is returned from the findById call I don't really have a mongoose object.  Meaning it does not have a populate method on it.

sure I can do this:

```
var mockedPerson = {
  _id: '1',
  name: 'test',
  employer: '12',
  populate: function() {
    return {
       name: 'test',
       employer: {
         name: 'Apple'
       }
    }
  }
};
```

Which seems hackish to mock the populate method in this way.  I am really trying to test the getPersonById method with a mock DB call, but I would still like to verify that I am calling populate with the correct arguments and maybe mock the return with sinon.

Is that possible?  I have tried something like this, but you cannot stub a method that does not exist.

```
var mockedPerson = {
  _id: '1',
  name: 'test',
  employer: '12'
};
var stub = sinon.stub(mockedPerson, 'populate')
  .withArgs('employer')
  .yields(null, { name: 'test', employer: 'apple'});
```